# How can I avoid multiple instances of an OMF while copying a session in ProTools?

Tags: pro-tools, post-production, omf, session-organization

My PT session for a short film has several audio tracks, and at some point I imported an OMF from the foley department.
I worked directly from this OMF (maybe the problem started here?) with editing, processing, etc.

Now that I was saving a copy of the session to another location, I was surprised to see that it required around 250 GB, where the Audio Files folder only was 16 GB. Not knowing where the issue was, I still made the copy.

Later on, checking the Audio Files folder of the copied session, I had over 400 instances of the OMF, all with the same creation date and most of them with the complete size. It seems that it´s an instance for every clip that was not processed.

For trying it out, I moved all OMF files, except one, to another folder and tried to open my session. ProTools still needed to locate the OMF´s or else the audio clips associated with it, would be stated as missing files.
I restored the OMF´s to the Audio Files folder, but ProTools is still not finding them.

Why is ProTools doing this and could I have avoided it by duplicated the OMF tracks and work from the copied audio clips?

I have ProTools 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I do is go to import session data, select copy audio from source media. Then, select source tracks i want to import to my working session. PT automatically select all tracks for you so, be careful to de-select unwanted tracks before hit OK.

One more thing. Make sure you check HIDE tracks before save  copy in and DON"T forget to remove unused regions before you save copy in.

Hope this help.